# is there some option in curl to set the tcp reset timeout?

Tags: http, curl, tcp, libcurl

I have a client and server using http to transmit files,
I used tcpdump found that, every time after recieving the http header,
the server sends a ack, 
but then the server receive 2 reset packet, some times recieve reset after successfully receiving a packet contain http content.

the timeline of tcpdump data at the server side looks likes bellow:

```
01:10:01.553222------data:http header
01:10:01.553233----------ack

01:10:01.590075-----------reset
01:10:01.590103-----------reset
```

the curl option setting code:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteData); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &sbuf);  
curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie");

curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, ReadCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_READDATA, this);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, block_size);


curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, ProgressCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_obj, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, this)
```

So, what I want to ask is, is there some options in libcurl to set the timeout for reset tcp when not recieving a sent data's ack in some limited time? if the client and server are in the same city and have a fast internet connection, this system works fine, so there should not be some bugs in the business code.

ps: curl returns errorno 56

Comment: Too many assumptions here. You are *assuming* that the resets are issued as a result of a timeout. They can be issued for other reasons. What behaviour are you experiencing at the application level that caused you to get this tcpdump?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple callback options that allow the application to access the socket directly, like [CURLOPT_SOCKOPTFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTSOCKOPTFUNCTION) and [CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTOPENSOCKETFUNCTION).

But like a commenter on this question, I doubt that is the actual reason (or solution) for your problem.